# Mostrar en pantalla un pdf encriptado

Tags: java, java-swing, contraseña

Por favor necesito ayuda desplegando un **pdf con contraseña** de apertura. He buscado en este sitio y otros sin mucha suerte ya que las soluciones que se propone es abrir el archivo encriptado y copiarlo a uno nuevo sin seguridades, lo cual es ilógico. Se trata de material con copyright así que no se desea que el usuario final conozca la contraseña.

**Lo que necesito es pasar la contraseña a adobe reader o google chrome para que se despliegue en pantalla el PDF encriptado y el usuario lo visualice**. Estoy trabajando con Java Swing siendo esta también una alternativa válida el abrirlo por medio de alguna herramienta. Ya he probado la librería Itext.

Comment: Puedes mandar un comando a la terminal y abrir adobe acrobat con parametros. Adobe Reader tiene algunas opciones para abrir los documentos y el código podria ser por ejemplo: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start "+"Ruta"); `Aunque esto solo permite que se ejecute en windows. Pero como abres tu pdf? Que tienes hasta ahora?

Comment: Saludos estimado si es una opcion pero no me permite enviarle la contraseña de apertura del archivo por medio de comandos al adobe reader, me sugirieron usar pdf.js ando investigando como hacerlo funcionar desde java ya que al momento me sa este error:

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "Promise" from undefined in <eval> at line number 1145

Answer (score 0):

Encontre esto por internet:

> Starting from iText 2.0.0 you need the BouncyCastle jars. You need to download it >from its site. More info can be found from here:
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

-

> Desde iText 2.0.0 necesitas jar BouncyCastle. Necesitas descargarlo de este sitio: http://www.bouncycastle.org/ Mas información puede encontrarse aqui:
>
> http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/java-lang-NoClassDefFoundError-org-bouncycastle-asn1-ASN1OctetString-td2151526.html

Esta es la pregunta:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/10878721/4326551

Te recomiendo leas la pregunta. Según los comentarios itext funciona bien.

Comment: Exacto si se abre efectivamente, incluso se copia a un archivo nuevo pero sin contraseña de apertura y eso no tiene sentido ya que el usuario final puede guardar la información que como mencionaba es sensible y con copyright. Como mencionaba lo que se necesita es que se abra en pantalla el archivo con seguridades ya que si lo copia cada que intente abrirlo le pedirá la contraseña que es lo que quiero enviar por código